# php PDO prepared statement doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Possible duplicate, but I lost hours on this one

```
                $stmt=$mysql->prepare(" insert into test_booked_tickets(book_id, ticket_id, num_people) values(:book_id,:ticket_id,:num)");
                echo (int)$ticket->id."<br/>";
                echo (int)$ticket->number_people."<br/>";
                echo (int)$booking->id."<br/>";
                $stmt->bindValue(":ticket_id", (int)$ticket->id);
                $stmt->bindValue(":num", (int)$ticket->number_people);
                $stmt->bindValue(":book_id", (int)$booking->id);

                try{
                    $stmt->execute();

                }
                catch(PDOException $e){
                    echo "catched <br/>";
                    echo $e->errorInfo;
                }
```

Other queries work perfectly. These are the returned values from echo 

30

1

10

It doesn't get into catch, and it doesn't insert into table...

Comment: Errors, if any? Are you checking for them?

Comment: PDO exception doesn't return anything, no php errors either

Comment: Did you enable ERRMODE_EXCEPTION? If not, did you check the return value from `execute()`? Did you check `$stmt->rowCount()` after the INSERT? Have you tried the SQL manually in the mysql client?

Comment: Add `$mysql->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after you init `$mysql`

Comment: Column lengths are long enough? Column type correct? Could be a number of things. SQL may be failing silently.

Comment: Maybe you have ANSI quotes on,so `bindvalue` won`t accept double quotes(wild guess)

Comment: One more idea: if you started a transaction somewhere prior in the application, and you neglect to commit, then the row will be discarded as the transaction rolls back.

Comment: Also try specifying the parameter type rather than casting directly to int.

Comment: A.O! Thanks for enabling error logs. Stupid me. Wrong column name.
I was really puzzled by catch not catching anything. 
Told you it's probably something stupid

Comment: I was going to suggest that but you said *"PDO exception doesn't return anything, no php errors either"* ;) which is why I didn't. (wink) and as Bill mentioned also.

Comment: Thanks everyone for wonderful work.

Comment: I tested the code and data were inserted to the table successfully ..

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for useful comments, I had a typo in database, column name.
Thanks A.O. for the most useful comment.

And thanks everyone else for other useful suggestions.